# Using and testing bouncer pattern in Typescript

Tags: typescript

For every project in our company we apply the [bouncer pattern](https://dev.polarion.com/polarion/sdk/doc/scriptlanguage-guides/groovy/html/documentation/design-pattern-bouncer.html) on any public methods that we write as part of our coding guidelines. Normally we would test this code using a simple test where we pass a null value through the public method, but since a couple months I've switched to a Typescript project and noticed that this works a bit different in Typescript. A simple sample null check that I use for this:

```
register(email: string): boolean {

  if (!email) {
    throw Error("Email cannot be undefined");
  };

  // do stuff
};
```

When I try to pass a undefined or null value through typescript in a test, I end up with a compile error, like such:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

I've tried to work around this for my test, but have not found anything that works yet. Is there a way that I can test these scenarios in Typescript or is there no point in using the bouncer pattern in Typescript?

Comment: You defined email to be a `string`. Undefined is not assignable to `string`. To avoid this error you'd have to write: `register(email: string | undefined): boolean { /*...*/ }`

Comment: Yes I'm aware of this, my question is more about whether it is possible for a parameter to be undefined even when I assigned it to an type at runtime (e.g. through an api call or something else external). If that isn't the case, then my usage of the bouncer pattern is unnecessary

Comment: I don't get it. @r3dst0rm's answer corresponds to what you want, doesn't it? If you can figure out a case where `email` could be `undefined`, and you consider that as a normal behavior, then type it as `string | undefined`; you can have your custom handler below in the method (as you did). If it is not supposed to happen in any scenario, then it is not a case to test

Comment: What I'm trying to figure out is if using`register(email: string)` 100% guarantees that email cannot be undefined or null. In my experiences in other languages this can still happen at runtime, like when an API call fails. If it is 100% guaranteed, then using the bouncer pattern in Typescript has no point and then it is not a case to test, like u said.

Comment: You should be able to 100% guarantee it. If you're passing in an API response that you can't guarantee is a string, then you need to check that _before_ you put it into the function.

Comment: So I have just done some testing and calling with an empty string `register("")` will actually come up as undefined in a null check even when you check for a string and use `register(email: string). Although I feel this case only works for strings, it shows that its not a 100% guarantee.

Comment: Basically if you don't do any side effects (e.g. API calls etc.) there should be no case where email could be undefined. Unless you write something like: `register(undefined as unknown as string)`. If you deal with API calls, I suggest to you, that you include `io-ts` and parse any API response. This ensures, that you have a defined barrier where it is safe to assume, you received a desired type.